# Tengo un error al compilar el metodo super() en JAVA

Tags: java, compilar

Tuve un error a la hora de compilar segun yo el metodo `super.toString()` esta bien escrito asi que no entiendo porque sale el error espero me puedan ayudar

[image: En la imagen se muestra el error de compilacion]

```
package personas;
public class Persona{
    protected String nombre;
    protected String fechaNacimiento;
    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }   
    public String getFechaNacimiento(){
        return this.fechaNacimiento;
    }
    public void setNombre(String n){
        this.nombre=n;
    }
    public void setFechaNacimiento(String fn){
        this.fechaNacimiento=fn;
    }
    public Persona(String n,String fn){
        this.nombre=n;
        this.fechaNacimiento=fn;
    }
    public String toString(){
       return "Nombre: "+nombre+"\tFecha de Nacimiento: "+fechaNacimiento;
    }
}
package personas;

public class Estudiante extends Persona{
    private String matricula;
    public void setMatricula(String m){
       this.matricula=m;
    }   
    public String getMatricula(){
        return this.matricula;
    }
    public Estudiante(String n,String fn,String m){
        super(n,fn);
        matricula=m;
    }
    public String toString(){
       return super.toString()+"\nMatricula: "+matricula;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La palabra reservada `super` en java se usa para acceder a los atributos y métodos de una clase padre, esta palabra va ligada a la herencia en java.
También se usa la palabra clave `super` para inicializar atributos de la clase padre a través del llamado desde los métodos constructores de las clases hijo.
Al poner

```
return super.toString()+"\nMatricula: "+matricula;
```

estas interpretando `Super` como una clase y que `toString()` es un método de `Super`,lo cual es incorrecto es por eso que te marca error.Si la clase `Estudiante` hereda de `Persona` basta que solo la clase hija tenga el método `toString()`y que tenga los valores propios y los heredados,evitando la declaración del método en la clase padre(HERENCIA).

Si por dato te dicen que la clase padre debe tener el método `toString()` entonces debes declararlo como un método abstracto

```
  public String toString(){
       return "\nMatricula: "+matricula+"Nombre: "+nombre+"\tFecha de Nacimiento: "+fechaNacimiento;
    }
}
```